# Proving that a sequence of random variables satisfies Lindeberg's condition

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes

I have a sequence of iid random variables $X_n$ with zero mean and constant variance $\sigma^2_n$. 
Let $S_n=\sum_{j=1}^{n}{(j-1)X_j}$. In order to prove asymptotic normality I need to prove first Lindeberg's condition.

Can anyone point me to the right direction?

Best regards,

Juan

Comment: Can you write the Lindeberg's condition?